# Is Snappy compressed Avro files queryable in Athena?

Tags: avro, amazon-athena, snappy

Regarding the Athena documentation, we cas use the Avro SerDe to query Avro files, which work for me ( CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE).

But regarding their documentation, Athena does only support Parquet and ORC format when dealing with snappy compression..
I don't understand, why should it be a dependency between the format and the compression for Athena

Is snappy compressed Avro files are not queryable by Athena , or this is just something not defined in their doc ?

Comment: Are you talking about querying existing files that are compressed Avro, or creating new files using a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS) statement and having those in compressed Avro format? There are different limitations on what Athena can query vs. what can be created.

Comment: It's more for querying existing files ( using CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE..) that are avro snappy compressed files ( or another compression codec if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and it does work fine. You can query s3 snappy compressed avro files with Athena

Comment: Worked for me also.